# Authentication for a local running application that uploads files

Tags: authentication, amazon-s3, local

**Scenario**

We want to authenticate a user for an application that runs locally and uploads some files to S3. Google cloud cli does an interesting way of validating the user by opening up the browser and sending the token back to a server running locally on port 8080 (or something). We could use this approach still we were wondering if there is another way to do it or someone has a different and possibly a better solution to this problem.

We do not want to store any keys/tokens on the local app, users should be able to authenticate as and when needed.

**Points to consider**

- We need to authenticate users on an application (executable) locally
- The application uploads files to S3
- We can do the authentication on our own with possibly a token
- Oauth is an option which are not fully in favor of so exploring other options.